# Should I put new DRAM in DIMM1 and move old DRAM to DIMM2?

Tags: performance, memory, benchmarking

I am using an Acer 4710g laptop, with 1G RAM on DIMM1, 512MB RAM on DIMM2 (or DIMM3, not sure)

I got a new 1G DDR2 PC-5300 DRAM. Should I move the old 1G RAM to DIMM2 and put new one in DIMM1? The reason is I guess the laptop will use DIMM1 first (or more frequently).

Is there any benchmark tool can see the memory performance to compare my new/old DDR RAM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For benchmarking I recommend you use [Passmark Performance Test](http://www.passmark.com/products/pt.htm).

As for what to put where, it is not important.

Both memory modules will either not work at all (rarely) or most likely only work at the speed of the slowest.

However, if the motherboard support dual channel memory, I would recommend that you get two matching sticks so that you can get this advantage. However, if you have already purchased the new memory and it doesn't work, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: But wouldn't the OS use DIMM1 RAM first, so means recharge RAM on DIMM1 more than DIMM2? Which causes the transistor on DIMM1 RAM is less endurance than DIMM2.

Comment: @Stan - The R in RAM stands for Random - you request 1MB, it can come from the first or the last. Memory is either fine and working or faulty and it then gets worse, out of all the errors I have ever seen, I have never come across a burnt out memory module.

Comment: But random does not mean you will have random access, but only random access ist possible and fast (without aligning heads like in disks). Though in reality, the use patterns are quite random, so you will not be able to tell which bar will get your data.